# I messed up Activating my Iphone 6

Tags: iphone

While activating my iphone, I accidentally skipped the section where you call and activate your phone. My phone isn't sending messages or calls, and cellular isn't working. Is there any other way I can make it work?

Comment: Ring your service provider [carrier]... from another phone

Answer (score 1):

What section where you call and activate your phone? there was no phone call involved in setting up the iPhone 6 (or my previous iPhones either).

If you are not getting any cellular services you will need to contact your carrier. The simplest way to do this is to call 611 from the phone, but they may need you to reset the phone (losing the call) so it may be simpler to just go to your carrier's closest brick-and-mortar store.

Comment: most of that answer would depend on which carrier you use, not relevant to anyone who doesn't share the same carrier.

Comment: Not really. 611 is the universal #11 for repair assistance (at least in the US) and works on all the mobile carriers. And contacting the carrier for cellular problems is the only solution that is going to work, regardless of who the carrier is.

Comment: ***At least in the US*** Do you realise that only 4% of the world's population lives in the US?

Comment: Are you suggesting that contacting the carrier is NOT the solution for cellular problems for 96% of the world? As I said, you can call 611 (which is not US only) **or** you can got to the carrier directly. Whatever you do, only the carrier is going o be able to fix a problem where you do not have cellular service. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6-1-1

Comment: no... I'm suggesting that providing phone numbers that are useless to 96% of the world's population is not the best Answer ever.

Comment: But 611 is used outside the US. As the wikiparticle says, "Many wireless phone providers also use 611 or *611 as a general customer service access number;" So, If you think that is wrong, go down-vote Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm out of this extended tennis game. If you cannot see how your reasoning fails, then I'm not going to persuade you in a couple of lines of chat. I downvoted you, let's hope others do too. To quote your wikipedia page, "For customers of some telephone companies in Canada and in the U.S." that makes ***some people in 2 countries***, not the whole world.